# Disable starting Jboss 5.1 as application in Mac OSX Lion

Tags: java, osx-lion, jboss5.x

I haven't found a better way to explain in the title what is going on when starting an old Jboss installation for development purpose, on Lion.

Basically, an org.jboss.Main application is started too. For "application" I mean that an icon (the classic cup of coffee one) in the Dock is created by Lion, and an immediate scroll to the main desktop occurs showing a org.jboss.Main menu item in the toolbar.
This item has the default mac entries: preferences, about, etc.

This is a Jboss installation I inherited, literally copy and pasted from a USB key.
I thought there must be a JAVA_OPTS causing this, because other Java app servers I have on my machine don't have such behavior.

thanks

Comment: You can try the -Djava.awt.headless=true switch in your JAVA_OPTS and see if it still appears

Comment: Try running the installation from Terminal and check if it shows any errors.

Comment: @DaTroop the settings works, don't know if this the preferred way. Anyway I cannot mark a comment as answer, if you want you can write an answer for me to mark as accepted.

Comment: I added it. Thanks! This is the preferred way because normally with an application server(or just servlet container) you do not need AWT/SWING and in this way you also save resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the -Djava.awt.headless=true switch in your JAVA_OPTS